# How to open a (html) file as a stream from the project in Java?

Tags: java, resources, class-method

This is what my project setup looks like:

[image: Picture of project setup. Packages and libraries]
'

I'm trying to open the base.html file with:

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/HttpServer/htmlFiles/base.html");
```

But it's always returning null. No variation of the path I use works ("/htmlFiles/base.html", "/base.html", "base.html"). I have also tried using HTML.class.getResourceAsStream() but the result is the same.

I tried to do this by making a separate source folder for the code and another for the files, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your project setup? (it's empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream in = HTML.class.getResourceAsStream("/htmlFiles/base.html");
```

should work. Are you sure you tried this one ?

Comment: I'm almost certain I did, but I never got it to work. This DID work now though. Thanks a lot. I was ready to give up on this!